# Getting correct ID in rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

When I do a rake routes,

```
GET       test/:test_id/associated_link(.:format)
GET       test/(.:format)
POST      test/(.:format)
GET       test/new(.:format)
GET       test/:id/edit(.:format)
PATCH     test/:id(.:format)
PUT       test/:id(.:format)
DELETE    test/:id(.:format)
```

I need the first instance to be test/:id/associated_link

Routes file looks like

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   resources :years
   resources :mateirals
   resources :people
   resources :jobs
   resources :test do
     get 'associated_links'
   end

   root 'welcome#index'
   resources :welcome, :companies, :positions
```

Comment: Please post your routes file.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You mean instead of `test/:test_id/associated_link(.:format)` you want `test/:id/associated_link(.:format)`?

Comment: The question is why is it showing test/:pws_id instead of test/:id like the rest of them.

Comment: @pavan yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be a member route.

```
   resources :test do
     member do
         get 'associated_links'
     end
   end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [member route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#2.10-Adding-More-restful-actions), which can be found in the docs. It will look like this:

```
resources :test do 
  member do
    get 'associated_links'
  end
end
```

or, if you only have a single member route, you can eliminate the block as such:

```
resources :test do 
  get 'associated_links', on: :member
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the URI Pattern to look like `test/:id/associated_link`, you need to change

```
resources :test do
   get 'associated_links'
end
```

to

```
resources :test do
   get 'associated_links', on: :member
end
```

***Tested***